# seperate string and remove url parameters

Tags: php

I have this code, the part I am looking for is the number from the url `1538066650683084805`

I use this example

`$tweet_url = 'https://twitter.com/example/status/1538066650683084805'`

```
    $arr = explode("/", $tweet_url);
    $tweetID = end($arr);
```

Which works however sometimes on phones, When people copy and paste the url it has parameters on the end of it like this;

`$tweet_url = 'https://twitter.com/example/status/1538066650683084805?q=2&t=1';`

When a URL is exploded with the URL above the code doesn't work, how do I get the number `1538066650683084805` in both uses.

Thanks so much.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest using [parse_url](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) to get just the path, then separate that out:

```
$url = parse_url('https://twitter.com/example/status/1538066650683084805?q=2&t=1');
/*
[
     "scheme" => "https",
     "host" => "twitter.com",
     "path" => "/example/status/1538066650683084805",
     "query" => "q=2&t=1",
   ]
*/
$arr = explode("/", $url['path']);
$tweetID = end($arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would explode first on the question mark and just look at the index `0`  .. THEN explode the slash ...

```
$tweet_url = 'https://twitter.com/example/status/1538066650683084805?q=2&t=1';

$tweet_url = explode('?', $tweet_url)[0];
$arr = explode("/", $tweet_url);

$tweetID = end($arr);
```

If the question mark does not exist -- It will still return the full URL in `$tweet_url = explode('?', $tweet_url)[0];` so it's harmless to have it there.

And this is just me .. But I would write it this way:

```
$tweet_url = 'https://twitter.com/example/status/1538066650683084805?q=2&t=1';

$tweetID = end(
              explode("/",
                 explode('?', $tweet_url)[0]
              )  
           );

echo $tweetID . "\n\n";
```